# ListAdapter with multiple sections

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Any idea how to implement [RecyclerView.**ListAdapter**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter) with multiple section and keep the functionality of `ListAdapter` (computing diffs)?

Comment: You should use different view types using _getItemViewType_ method

Answer (score 0):

In your model class you have to create on field for identify the viewType then just override this method in your listAdapter

```
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    //        Based on position set here view type / section type
        val myModel = getItem(position)
        when(myModel.viewType){
            isBanner -> 
            isVerticalList ->
            isTextField ->
            else -> 
        }
        }
```

Return type is integer value so you can simply return view id itself like `R.id.banner_type`

and then

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int){
        when(viewType){

        }
    }
```